# VBA Form dynamic hyperlink from current record

Tags: forms, vba, hyperlink, record

I have a search form. If I double click on of the items, a new form opens with the selected record, where you can see the details about it. I store an ID, what I can use to open a webpage like `https://mywebpage.net/asd/ID`. So I want to concatenate my base url (`https://mywebpage.net/asd/`) with the ID, but it doesn't work. I tried `"https://mywebpage.net/asd/" & me.I`D, but when I click on it, Access says only `"https://mywebpage.net/asd/"` without the ID. Can you help me how to create a hyperlink on the details form, which navigate to the current element's webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out!
Base url: `="https://myanimelist.net/anime/" & me.malid`